# I can't run Blizzard Battle.net installer on WINE

Tags: wine, games

This is my first time trying to use WINE and the whole experience is a bit overwhelming! But I am reading as much as I can and so far I have tried using q4wine and also `wine <path to .exe>` and both end up crashing with a failure. this is the error in the bash

```
dj@dj-GE62-6QF:~/Downloads$ wine Battle.net-Setup.exe 
0009:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://www.blizzard.com/404">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
GIF89aÇ    ,D;<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://www.blizzard.com/404">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
003f:err:ole:CoCreateInstanceEx apartment not initialised
003f:err:ntdll:NtQueryInformationToken Unhandled Token Information class 24!
0041:err:ntdll:NtQueryInformationToken Unhandled Token Information class 24!
0041:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
GIF89aÇ    ,D;<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://www.blizzard.com/404">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
dj@dj-GE62-6QF:~/Downloads$ 0067:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
wine: Call from 0x7b43c8bc to unimplemented function msvcp140.dll.?uncaught_exceptions@std@@YAHXZ, aborting
007e:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
```

and then the blizzard launcher says this...

error screen shot:

[image: error screen shot]

I am totally new to linux and wine. Can someone please tell me how to fix this, or if it can be fixed? I tried with winecfg set to both windows 7 and windows 10

Thanks in advanced

Comment: WINE is complicated and can be unstable with some programs, .dll and configs. You install Lutris with wine and try this installation script: https://lutris.net/games/battlenet/

Comment: Okay. So just to be clear... and again sorry I am asking for such basic level help, sudo apt-get wine64, then same with lutris? or should I use the synaptic package manager? The thing that scares me of synaptic is the myriad options of "wine" downloads and the fact that I am not quite sure which one I should be choosing nor do I know if downloading multiple of said packages will make the appropriate one run improperly. I am trying to learn all this stuff but don't even know where to begin. I hope you guys can be patient with me.

Comment: Sorry i misspoke. I meant install lutris then use the WINE functionality of lutris. It is better to install WINE from their repositories instead of Ubuntu repos. https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu If you installed it from Ubuntu repos and then you install from WINE repos it should remove the old one (BTW warning with synaptic. It can be dangerous because it shows every packages. You should only touch at wine, wine64 and winehq-stable). Install Lutris https://lutris.net/downloads/ and try this installation script for the game https://lutris.net/games/battlenet/ and tell it to use WINE (system).